# Multiple Level Reflection in C#

Tags: c#, web, reflection

I am trying to write a function which can take in a URI and then map that to a function in C#. The intention is to have a single object in C# which has a number of functions or members which can be called. This would be similar to the Method Dispatcher in CherryPy.

I am most of the way there, but am stuck at grabbing the object in C# when reflecting through multiple layers. At current I have a function which will recurs through several layers of member object but this is done using types, and not the direct objects.

I find this hard to explain so hopefully the code below will clarify the issue (I have removed all error checking and the out clause).

The problem I have is that when calling MethodInfo.Invoke, I do not have the physical object reference to pass in as the first parameter.

I believe I should be able to get the object reference somehow from "fieldInfo" If somebody can tell me how to do that I believe I can complete this function.

```
{
 List<String> path = request.Url.AbsolutePath.Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList<String>();
 object[] parameters = new object[2] { request, response };
 System.Type controllerType = Controller.GetType();

 MethodInfo methodInfo = GetMethod(path, controllerType);

 methodInfo.Invoke(<I DONT HAVE THIS OBJECT>, parameters);
}

private MethodInfo GetMethod(List<String> path, System.Type type)
{
 MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod(path[0], BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
 if(methodInfo != null)
 { 
  return methodInfo;
 }

 FieldInfo fieldInfo = type.GetField(path[0].ToString());

 path.RemoveAt(0);
 return GetMethod(path, fieldInfo.FieldType);
}
```

Comment: Have you considered just using WebAPI? It already does this.

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017564/url-mapping-with-c-sharp-httplistener

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the object reference from the [`FieldInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Type information including field information is metadata that is [shared across all instances of the same type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  If you create 100 instances of type `T`, to which one should the shared type information refer?

However, you state "The intention is to have a single object in C# which has a number of functions or members which can be called."  Thus it sounds like the [generic](http://neutrofoton.com/generic-singleton-pattern-in-c/) [singleton pattern](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx) may work for you:

```
public static class SingletonHelper
{
    public static T GetInstance<T>() where T : class
    {
        return Singleton<T>.Instance;
    }

    public static object GetInstance(Type type) 
    {
        if (type == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (!type.IsClass)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        var genericType = typeof(Singleton<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { type });
        return genericType.GetProperty("Instance", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).GetValue(null, null);
    }
}

public class Singleton<T> where T : class
{
    // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
    // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
    static Singleton()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Private nested class which acts as singleton class instantiator. This class should not be accessible outside <see cref="Singleton<T>"/>
    /// </summary>
    class Nested
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler not to mark type as beforefieldinit
        /// </summary>
        static Nested()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Static instance variable
        /// </summary>
        internal static readonly T instance = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), true);
    }        

    public static T Instance { get { return Nested.instance; } }
}
```

Here you would call `SingletonHelper.GetInstance(type)`.  This requires that your code be working with only one [`AppDomain`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178514/is-there-any-situation-i-get-two-different-singletons-in-the-same-application/15178547#15178547).  If not, this won't work.